# Why when i call a sqltie 3 cursor.,execute in a tkinter button command it doesn't work?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Hello I want to make a postit app with python module named tkinter and sqlite 3 bcs i want the notes to keep for later on and i got stuck at when the player haves to save a postit text that he changed because when i put the command to update the text of a item of the sqlite 3 table on a button command it downt work. Sorry i'm bad at exaplaining heres the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

# database name = postits

conn = sqlite3.connect("dbs\postit.db")
row = 1

cursor = conn.cursor()

posts = cursor.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM postits")

postsFetch = posts.fetchall()

print(f"{postsFetch}")

def createPost():
    for postit in postsFetch:
        if postit[1] == "name":
        print("ok")

# here is the problem: if call the function like bellow it works perfectly
def savePost():
    cursor.execute(f"""UPDATE postits SET content = 'test02' WHERE name = 'name'""")
    print(postsFetch)

savePost()

#but if I call it in a button function it doesn't work
saveBtn = Button(post,text="Save",command=savePost)
```

so that's the problem if u don't understand something tell me and i'll try to explain better

Comment: You're missing `(` in `conn = sqlite3.connect"dbs\postit.db")`

Comment: The `savePost()` function doesn't use `postName` or `content` parameters.

Comment: no this is fine i just changed the connect path bcs it was my computer path but i put the parenthesis everywhere and it connets the database succesfully

Comment: I'm sure it's another copying error, but the `print("ok")` statement isn't indented correctly. Please post valid code.

Comment: There's no `name` or `text` variables.

Comment: The SQL has hard-coded values and not using the passed arguments, so how do you expect it works with the value you input?

Comment: now i put everything in order but it doesnt work

Comment: i put "test02" as a test to see if it works then when I will know it works i will put the input

Comment: Do you mean that `print(postsFetch)` does not show the new value of the UPDATE statement? If it is, then the reason is that `postsFetch` is the result of SELECT (at program start) before the UPDATE statement (when the button is clicked).

Comment: yh i though it too but i restarted the app several time and the name didn't change neither

Comment: Do you have a record with `name = 'name'`?  If not, then your UPDATE will not update any record.

Comment: maybe the second option because i got an item called name, let me explain it better: When i call the function in the file without the command= it works, it changed the value but when i call it in the command= i doesn't work like i commeanted in the post

Comment: nvm i done it i should put conn.commit() in the function